# By the side of / by / beside / next to / close to

Tags: prepositions, difference

> I was sitting **next to / by / by the side of / beside / close to ** my friend.

As a learner all of the preparations means **near or close to** to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all these prepositions mean **close to**.
**by the side of** is generally used for non-living things.

> My house is situated by the side of the river.

**next to** means **right after somebody/something**

If B sits next to A there is no one sitting between A and B.

If someone sits **by/close to** you it does not necessarily mean they are next to you but they are close to you.